# does anyone know how to drag from the first bottom cell to the right without having empty or 0 cells but having a,b,c,d cells following each other?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this top array in which each cell consists of some merged columns. when I write `=O9` in another cell and drag it to the right, it gives me some empty cells which I don't want. But how to drag it and fill the cells like having an `a` in the first cell and the `b` in the next and so on?
[image]

Comment: Are you just trying to replicate what's on row 9 in that lower row? Why are you putting O9 as the formula and not P9?

Comment: @FlexYourData Yeah i'm trying to do that but the ```P9``` results yet another ```0``` !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your column headers are showing in reverse. Perhaps this is a culture or regional setting but I've never seen that before.

Anyway, you can use something like this:

[image]

In cell R19, I have this formula:

```
=IF(R8=0,Q19,R8)
```

This says

> if R8, i.e. the value in row 8 of this column, is zero (i.e. blank), then use the value in the cell to the left of this cell, otherwise use the value from row 8.

This will also work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(R8),Q19,R8)
```

EDIT:

To get your required output, you can use this:

```
=FILTER($R$8:$Y$8,$R$8:$Y$8<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: aabbbcdd! thanks for trying to help but it's not what is needed. the desired answer would result to four cells one after the other like this: a,b,c,d.

Comment: Made an edit which I think will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks man.. but unfortunately the FILTER function is only available to those on a Microsoft 365 subscription. It is not available in Excel 2019 or earlier versions :/